# page-break-inside not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing-web-page, page-break-inside

```
<div class="parentElement">
    <div class="content-container">
        someContentFromApi
    </div>
    <div class="map-container">
        <div>
            <ng-map>Google maps is displayed here</ng-map>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS file is as follows:

```
@media print {
    .map-container {
        position: relative;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        // page-break-before: always; //I've tried uncommenting it

        div {
            height: 400px;
        }
    }
    .content-container {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

I've setup my page as above. When I preview the page in print mode in chrome, the map is getting cut. 
I tried everything like putting page-break-inside: avoid on map-container, page-break-after: always on content-container but nothing seem to work.

I found posts related to page-inside-break property but none seem to work, that's why I made this post. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or there's any other way of achieving page break in print mode.

Comment: Posting your CSS would help. Also, have you tried putting page-break-before:always on your map container?

Comment: @ecg8 Yes I've tried page-break-before:always on map container but that dint work. I've added css code for reference.

Comment: Have you tried removing the sytles for the div from the media query? I removed them and it works for me in JSBin https://jsbin.com/babucowusu

Comment: You've defined separate divs on same page, they're not separate pages. Try removing page-break property you'll still get the same output. @ecg8